# Cannot add new SO Line items

Tags: acumatica

I have recently installed and deployed new instance of Acumatica ver 6.10.0010 and restore one of the customer's snapshot.

I cannot add new line items irrespective of any order type. I have even unpublished all customizations but still cannot add. I have checked on customer's site, where I am able to add new line items. What could be the possible cause?

Comment: I assume the orders are not on hold? possibly could be related to user permissions to the sales order screen? I don't think the user settings are transferred/replaced with snapshots.

Comment: Oops just missed that, that was quick. But thought admin user will have full rights. Thank you.

Comment: They should have full rights. However i have seen in the past that a user can create a mess of the admin permissions. But that was a long time ago since i played with the permission settings. Good to see you got it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User permission issue. After restore of snapshot, make sure to check for user permission, even if it is for admin.